# How to return something without quotation marks when using format()

Tags: python, formatting

In my code, I use format() to return the value of converted minuets.

```
def convert(minutes):
    return'{seconds}'.format(seconds = minutes*60)
```

Every time I use format to return a function it returns it with quotation marks ' '.

Input:

```
convert(10)
```

Output:

```
'600'
```

How do I use format to return the function without the quotation marks?

Comment: Do you mean you want the returned value to be a number rather than a string?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be returned as number without the quotation marks

Comment: The quotation marks only indicate it's a string, they're not part of the actual value. What do you want to do with that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are seeing the output directly from the console, and the variable is a string so python adds the quotation marks to let you know.

To remove them:

```py
print(convert(10))
```

Comment: Thank you this kind of helped. But it's only for when I enter the number out of the console